# ToolBar View Controller Parent Class not displaying properly

Tags: ios, swift

So I made a View Controller containing my toolBar's functions. For some reason when I make my other View Controller a subClass of my ToolBar View Controller my toolBar won't show the right color's and buttons from the ToolBar View Controller. It works for some other View Controller's so I'm a little confused.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Toolbar: UIViewController {
    
    var playBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
    var pauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem()
   
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
        navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        navigationController?.toolbar.isTranslucent = false
        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    
        self.playBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play , target: self, action: #selector(playBtnAction(sender:)))
        self.pauseBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause , target: self, action: #selector(pauseBtnAction(sender:)))
    
        playBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white
        pauseBtn.tintColor = UIColor.white

        toolbarItems = [playBtn, pauseBtn]
    
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    

  }
    
    
}

import Foundation
import UIKit

class TestVC: Toolbar {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    }


    
}
```

Comment: Well, isn't a bit odd that you have something called Toolbar but it is _not_ a toolbar (a UIToolbar) but a UIViewController?

Comment: Yeah, a little bit lol. What do you suggest?

Comment: Well as a matter of style a view controller's class's name should end with ViewController. :) Or at least Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to call `super`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() // <-- add this
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
}
```

*Always* call `super` in `viewDidLoad`, for this very reason. The superclass may have work to do, and if you don't call `super`, it can't do that work.